# Latest web application features

Tags: web-applications

What kind of features web users are expecting or excited about? I am aware of Ajax. Any thing else? I dont understand how tags are important even on this stackoverflow site. I dont understand how wiki is an important feature? I see that questions get "kicked" in terms of improtance or relevance but still dont understand full impact of it.

Where could I get information on latest and greatest expectations on a data driven web site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522530/latest-evoluations-in-web-content-display

Answer (score 3):

Rather then ask your question here to a bunch of engineers.  You should interview potential  customer in your target demographic.  Don't look for what is flashy and cool look for what best solves your customers problem.